# which files/folders to exclude from source control

Tags: tortoisesvn, mstest

Im setting up a unit test project and using SVN for source control.  There are two nuget packages used.  Im not sure if I need to exclude the files being generated or not.

MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0  and  MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0

When I go to commit the files within my branch, I see a lot of what look like new files being added in this folder *MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0/build*.  eg.

```
MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0/build
MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0/build/_common/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
```

Can I exclude everything from build/* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't keep Nuget packages in svn. In Visual Studio 2017 they are not event located in your project folder structure, but in `%HOME%\.nuget\packages`. Reference: [Should we include Nuget PACKAGE folder in version control?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/301547)

I would add whole `packages` folder to ignored if I were you.